# Overlapping charts in `matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation` overwrite the alpha parameter

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a random walk in two ways:

1. static using `plot` method from `matplotlib.pyplot`,
2. animated using `FuncAnimation` from `matplotlib.animation`.

The first one works pretty well, you can see an example of a really simple Brownian motion below.

[image: Static Brownian motion]

I tried to implement the code which would be capable of animating the random walk however I struggle with colors and the alpha parameter.

First of all the `alpha` parameter does not work. After successive iterations, the points overlap losing their transparency. In addition, the colors of the individual points change in each iteration, making the animation very unreadable.

You can see one animation below. The paths are the same as in the figure above.

[image: Animated Brownian motion]

The code I used to create the animation.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter


class Plotter:

    def __init__(self, paths, link, annotate, grid, save, alpha, cmap):

        self._paths = paths
        self._link = link
        self._annotate = annotate
        self._alpha = alpha
        self._cmap = cmap

        self._fig, self._ax = plt.subplots()
        self._animation = None

        if grid:
            self._ax.grid()

        self._plot()

        if save:
            self._check_path()
            self._filename = self._create_filename()
            self._save()

    def _plot(self):
        self._animation = FuncAnimation(
            self._fig, self._anim,  interval=500, frames=len(self._paths[0][0]), repeat=False,
        )

    def _anim(self, frame):
        self._ax.set_title(f'Frame: {frame}')
        for path in self._paths:
            x, y = path

            if self._link:
                self._ax.plot(x[:frame+1], y[:frame+1], linestyle='--', marker='o', alpha=self._alpha)
            else:
                self._ax.scatter(x[:frame+1], y[:frame+1], alpha=self._alpha, cmap=self._cmap)

    def _save(self):
        self._animation.save(self._filename, dpi=300, writer=PillowWriter(fps=25))

    @staticmethod
    def _check_path():
        if not os.path.exists('figures/'):
            os.mkdir('figures/')

    @staticmethod
    def _create_filename():
        filename = 'figures/{name}.gif'
        name = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
        return filename.format(name=name)
```

And that's how I created the `.gif`.

```
paths = [
    (
        [0, -0.6655408436280401, 0.10568259609257569, -0.26149279371869266, -0.5009666521908381, 0.3639625899869371, -0.49976435812228837, -0.48682212081220344, -1.2885433457534117, -0.9850803395821125, -0.018343580936876158],
        [0, -0.7463614308516193, -1.3829259649135648, -0.45277423905538894, 0.5181285733354615, 1.0200223928090424, 1.523982469709905, 2.5238987154492216, 3.1215968645836893, 4.074440085625576, 4.330213499967454]),
    (
        [0, 0.06636040923368702, 0.05255193650063124, 0.597356910675901, -0.2793019906386772, -0.894506810533089, 0.06788127670582911, -0.3820663494179474, -0.3801418070740879, 0.6063698370900061, -0.3466678114238062],
        [0, 0.9977957186149565, 1.9977003771103456, 1.1591375946582005, 1.6402500251210983, 2.4286173440649295, 2.700295774457584, 3.5933507188734235, 2.593352570806755, 2.4296614716942626, 2.732513317512087]
    )
]

Plotter(paths=paths, link=True, annotate=False, grid=True, save=True, alpha=0.5, cmap='Pastel1')
```

Is it possible to set fixed colours for individual points and a fixed value for the alpha parameter?

Answer (score 0):

A way to approach this is by creating two empty plots (one for each path) in your `init` function when and update the plots at each frame. You can fix the values for `alpha` and `color` while doing that.
Following that, it's also a good idea to fix the limits of your plot to prevent the plot from jumping from frame to frame.
At each frame, you can then update your plots with the values from your `paths` variable by using the `set_data` function (see doc [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html)).

See the code you provided with the edit I suggested:

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter
import numpy as np

class Plotter:

  def __init__(self, paths, link, annotate, grid, save, alpha, cmap):

    self._paths = paths
    self._link = link
    self._annotate = annotate
    self._alpha = alpha
    self._cmap = cmap

    self._fig, self._ax = plt.subplots()
    self._animation = None

    #Create a list of two empty placeholder plots and initialize alpha and color
    self._lns=[self._ax.plot([],[], linestyle='--', marker='o',alpha=self._alpha,color='tab:blue'),self._ax.plot([],[], linestyle='--', marker='o',alpha=self._alpha,color='tab:orange')] 
    self._ax.set_xlim([-2,2]) #set xlim
    self._ax.set_ylim([-2,5]) #set ylim

    if grid:
        self._ax.grid()

    self._plot()

    if save:
      self._check_path()
      self._filename = self._create_filename()
      self._save()

  def _plot(self):
    self._animation = FuncAnimation(self._fig, self._anim,  interval=500, frames=len(self._paths[0][0]), repeat=True)
      
  def _anim(self, frame):
    self._ax.set_title(f'Frame: {frame}')
    for i,path in enumerate(self._paths):
      x, y = path

      if self._link:
        self._lns[i][0].set_data(x[:frame+1], y[:frame+1]) #update values of the plots
        
  def _save(self):
    self._animation.save(self._filename, dpi=300, writer=PillowWriter(fps=2))
              
  @staticmethod
  def _check_path():
    if not os.path.exists('figures/'):
      os.mkdir('figures/')

  @staticmethod
  def _create_filename():
    filename = 'figures/{name}.gif'
    name = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
    return filename.format(name=name)
```

And the output gives:

[image]